# I cannot see the images, and it was not like this at the beginning, what do I need to do?

Tags: support, status-norepro

I cannot see the images, and it was not like this at the beginning, what do I need to do?

When I wrote an answer for instance

[How many resonance structures does the oxalate ion have?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/95141/how-many-resonance-structures-does-the-oxalate-ion-have)

I was very well able to see the image I put. I did not change any of my browser properties, or reinstall anything related to it.

Comment: I can't see images either because it's blocked in Iran. What ortho said. Try using a VPN instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no problem on my end, so unfortunately, it is quite likely to be something on your end.

Images on Stack Exchange are hosted on Imgur (https://i.stack.imgur.com/). I would suggest the possibility that Imgur is blocked in the country from which you are accessing the Internet.

Comment: You are right, it seems. I could not even use Tor directly since it has also got censored in Turkey, but this event is quite new, in a couple of days. I haven't even seen the news related to it.
Anyway, thank you very much.